# Rotation issue: DetailView is empty

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller

I develop a iPad App with has one UISplitViewController. In the DetailView is a TabBarController with some NavigationControllers.

My Problem is that: The Detail View is Black when i start the App in Landscape, Home Button Right. When i turn the iPad around that the Home Button is on the left side, the Detail View shows content. When i start the App in Landscape, Home Button Left all works fine.

I tested several things, like rebooting the device or modify the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, but nothing helped.

Comment: How are you setting the detail view controller up?

Comment: I add a UITabBarController in the IB at the index 1 of the UISplitViewController. Is this what you want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 4 Problem. Fixed in newer Versions.